# Queue Laravel No Guarda

Tags: php, laravel-8

Estoy teniendo problemas con el job y queue en laravel 8, ejecuto el comando

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Job:

```
public function __construct($email,$title,$products)
{
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->products = $products;
}
public function handle()
{
    $email = new StockProductMailable($this->title,$this->products);
    Mail::to($this->email)->send($email);
}
```

Proceso de envió de Email:

```
public function __construct($title,$products)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->products = $products;
}
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx')
        ->subject($this->title)
        ->view('mails.stock')
        ->with([
            'title' => $this->title,
            'products' => $this->products
        ]);
}
```

El cual sale que el proceso se realizo correctamente pero no se guarda la información del job en la base de datos, coloque como conexión de queue:database

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta agregando el código de lo que tienes en el Job, seria de mayor ayuda poder verlo

Comment: Donde esperas que se guarde la información del job?  El registro de la tabla de jobs de BBDD se elimina una vez el proceso es ejecutado.

Comment: El proceso cuando es ejecutado en consola no sale error, es decir que nunca se va guardar información en la tabla cuando termina el proceso el Job ??